# Как сделать скроллбар тонким в поле textarea (без JS)?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать скроллбар тонким в поле textarea (без JS)?

Вот таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
textarea {width:200px;height:80px;resize:none;}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  width: 6px; 
  height: 6px; 
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece { 
  background:transparent; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical { 
  height: 5px; 
  background-color: #cccccc; 
}
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal { 
  width: 5px; 
  background-color: #cccccc; 
}
```

```html
<textarea>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</textarea>
```

Comment: А нельзя какой нибудь одной настройкой сказать хрому показывать мобильный скроллбар, а не самому рисовать его?

Comment: @Khipster, нет. К сожалению, только так. Сам искал когда-то :(

Comment: Спасибо, сам нарисовал такой же как в гугл хроме?

Comment: @Khipster, по вашей картинке рисовал

Answer (score 0):

Вот набросал вам [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/ze1g15gh/3/)

а [тут](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) еще информация

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 8px;
     }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
   }
```

Comment: А нельзя какой нибудь одной настройкой сказать хрому показывать мобильный скроллбар, а не самому рисовать его?